# How can I tell mkvirtualenv which version of Python I'd like to use?

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm puzzled over the version of Python the gets installed when using `mkvirtualenv`. Outside of any virtualenv here's what I have.

```
$ which python 
/opt/local/bin/python    << MacPorts installed Python
$ python -V
Python 2.7.13
$ python -c "import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION"
OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
```

OK so far.

Now, make virtualenv...

```
$ mkvirtualenv foo
[normal stuff here]
(foo) $ which python
/Users/me/Workspace/venvs/foo/bin/python
(foo)$ python -V
Python 2.7.10
```

Why is this python 2.7.10? and not python 2.7.13?

```
$ python -c "import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION"
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
```

Where'd this come from?

How can I tell `mkvirtualenv` which version of Python I'd like to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `-p` (or `--python` option) to specify python executable path:

```
mkvirtualenv -p `which python` foo
```

To be exact, [it's `virtualenv` option](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/#cmdoption-p). [`mkvirtualenv`](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#mkvirtualenv) passes unknown options to `virtualenv` directly.

Comment: mkvirtualenv -p c:\python37\python.exe new_env