# Install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper on MacOS

Tags: python-3.x, macos, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

How to install and configure `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` for `Python` on `MacOS`?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

To install `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` for repetitive use you need a correctly configured `Python` (this example uses `Python 3.x` but process is identical for `Python 2.x`).

Although you can get `python` [installer from Python website](https://www.python.org/downloads/) I strongly advice against it. The most convenient and future-proof method to install `Python` on `MacOS` is [brew](https://brew.sh/).

Main difference between installer from Python website and `brew` is that installer puts `python` packages to:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.x
```

`Brew` on the other hand installs `Python`, `Pip` & `Setuptools` and puts everything to:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.x/site-packages
```

And though it may not make any difference to you now – it will later on.

### Configuration steps

1. Install `brew`

---

Check out `brew` [installation page](https://brew.sh/) or simply run this in your terminal:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

2. Install `Python`

---

To install `python` with `brew` run:

```
brew install python3
```

Now your system needs to know where to look for freshly installed `Python` packages. Add this line to youre `~/.zshrc` (or `~/.bash_profile` if you're using `bash`):

```
export PATH=/usr/local/share/python:$PATH
```

**Restart your terminal.**
To make sure you've done everything correctly run `which python3` and in return you should receive `/usr/local/bin/python`.

3. Install `virtualenv` & `virtualenvwrapper`

---

Now it's time to install `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` to be able to use `workon` command and switch between virtual environments. This is done using `pip`:

```
pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

4. Set up `virtualenv` variables

---

Define a default path for your virtual environments. For example you can create a hidden directory inside `~` and called it `.virtualenvs` with `mkdir ~/.virtualenvs`. Add `virtualenv` variables to `.zshrc` (or `.bash_profile`).

Final version of your `.zshrc` (or `.bash_profile`) should contain this information for installed packages to work correctly:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3 installed by brew
export PATH=/usr/local/share/python:$PATH

# Configuration for virtualenv
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

**Restart your terminal.** You should be able to use `mkvirtualenv` and `workon` commands including autocompletion.

Here's [a little tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43664518/4726424) on how to create virtualenv with specific
version of Python.

> In case you are using `MacOS Mojave` and you are installing `Python3.6`
> from brew bottle you might have a problem with `pip`, [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/29176#issuecomment-398656987)'s a
> solution that might help.

---

With time some of you may want to install multiple `Python` versions with multiple virtual environments per version. When this moment comes I strongly recommend swithing to [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) and [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv) .

Comment: Perfect solution and explanation. I initially installed Python 3.6 using the installer but found that to be a huge headache - would recommend using Homebrew as well.

Comment: It seems that brew-installed `python3` may not put Python packages where this answer expects. From my `brew install python` I got: 
```
...
You can install Python packages with
  pip3 install <package>
They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
...
```

Comment: @Michael I didn't think someone will be checking full path to site packages, so in regards to your comment I've concatenated missing part of path where packages are installed.

Comment: For big sur


```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/opt/homebrew/bin/virtualenv
source /opt/homebrew/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: Help! How to uninstall python3 if installed via the python website? I have something confusing where I've installed both from the site and from brew. I see `/Applications/Python 3.9` but no uninstaller.

Comment: What does this mean? "Add virtualenv variables to .zshrc (or .bash_profile)."

Comment: @DrManhattan thank you very much!!! These paths are correct for Mac with BigSur OS with M1 and python installed in the correct way using brew.

Comment: Coming to this answer only to see that I have already upvoted it at some point in the past... the real MVP is you, @StanReduta

Answer (score 16):

Mac Big Sur
Python 3.8

## installation

`pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper`

or

`pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper --user`

## create directoty in your Home

`mkdir .virtualenvs`

## edit profile

`vi .bash_profile`

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3

export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs

export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/Users/{your_user}/Library/Python/3.8/bin/virtualenv

source /Users/{home_directory}/Library/Python/3.8/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

- check path with 'which' command or 'find':

## Reload .bash_profile

`source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: ~/ means home directory - /Users/{your_user}
Its a hidden file so you may need to press the Option key while viewing in Mac in Finder.

Comment: .bash_profile is usually in home directory

Answer (score 11):

### I'm running `macOS 10.15.7`

#### I followed official docs until [here](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#lazy-loading)

and change it to

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs

export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3

# export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/virtualenv

# source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

#### in your case try to run `which virtualenv` or `which python` to get exact paths

Answer (score 9):

### If you are using MacOS

**1.**

Install virtualenvwrapper

```
pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
```

---

**2.**

Create the "virtualenvs" folder

```
mkdir ~/.virtualenvs
```

---

**3.**

> Before you export this, make sure you are doing it in your project folder,
> because that's where you will activate the virtualenv

Export

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
```

next, write down in terminal `which python3`, to find the path and add it after the "=" sign

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=
```

in my case:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
```

to find the virtualenv path write in the terminal `which virtualenv`

add the path after the "=" sign

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=
```

in my case:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/virtualenv
```

---

**4.**

Last step is to add the source in the terminal

almost the same as the path you got when writing `which virtualenv`

The difference is the "wrapper.sh" in the end.

in my case

```
source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

---

**5.**

Now you can create the virtualenv name by doing the following:

```
mkvirtualenv nameOfTheVirtualEnviroment
```

in my case

```
mkvirtualenv venv
```

On this [Mozila page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/development_environment#using_a_virtual_environment) you can learn how to use it

Comment: Please comment, what's missing in my instruction.

Comment: MacOS 10.5.7 i was finding it difficult to  find mkvirtualenv command. 

your instructions really helped. thanks.

Comment: my terminal gets killed when I type the `source ...` command at step4.

Comment: @AnumSheraz I don't know why it does that. It works for most people, but something is wrong for you. Are you using MacOS, or maybe the version you using might not work for this or something else.

Answer (score 2):

I had many problems to install the virtualenvwrapper in my mac os (big sur) but after I spent my whole sunday on that I finally got it. What I did I do:

1. I reinstalled python3 using the homebrew. For some reason homebrew
   put your files in a non conventional directories (for exemple:
   /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 or /opt/homebrew/bin/virtualenv)
2. Than I installed the virtualenv (even its already installed in python3
   by default) and I installed virtualenvwrapper in sudo mode: sudo pip3
   install virtualenvwrapper (without sudo, I could't find the
   virtualenvwrapper.sh using whichvirtualenvwrapper).
3. After that, in my home directory (/˜), I created the .bashrc file using
   touch .bashrc because this file didn't existed in my home directory.
4. I used the command "which python3", "which virtualenv" and "which
   virtualenvwrapper.sh" to get the localization of them (it's important to
   get these location to fill the .bashrc file later). The result was:

   - /opt/homebrew/bin/python3
   - /opt/homebrew/bin/virtualenv
   - /opt/homebrew/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
5. Than, using vim editor, I wrote in this file like this:

   export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
   export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
   export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
   export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/opt/homebrew/bin/virtualenv
   source /opt/homebrew/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
6. Than, I saved this file using :wq command and run it using this command:
   source .bashrc
7. Than I testes using the writing "workon" command. It showed nothing so
   it worked
8. Finally I create a virtual environment. It worked.

I made a lot of mistakes and I really hope I did't damage my OS.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution worked for me. I have checked for the python path using `which python3.8` in my MAC laptop with OS Big Sur (11.4)

`/Users/apple/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3.8`

Also checked for `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`

```
/Users/apple/opt/anaconda3/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Updated my ~/.bash_profile with the above mentioned paths as shown below.

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Users/apple/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3.8
source /Users/apple/opt/anaconda3/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Then I was successfully able to source ~/.bash_profile.

Answer (score 0):

this solution also works for version 11.1

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs

export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3

# export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/virtualenv

# source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my config running on Macbook M1

```
# Configuration for virtualenv
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS=' -p /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3.11 '
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3.11
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages:$PATH"

source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

Stan's solution required different .bash_profile modification for me:
(macOS Catalina & Python 3.6)     Please make sure you change the version path from "..../3.6/..." to your version.  You can use "which python3" command to find out python path and "which virtualenv" for virtualenv path

```
### BEGIN: for virtualenvwrapper #########################
# Setting PATH for Python 3 installed by brew
# commented the Python path because I have already had that, you might have too.
# PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3:${PATH}"
# export PATH
# Configuration for virtualenv
WORKON_HOME="${HOME}/.virtualenvs"
export WORKON_HOME

VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3"
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/virtualenv"
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV
source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
### END: for virtualenvwrapper #########################
```

Comment: From the snippet you've provided it looks like you've installed `python` with `installer` rather then `brew`, so that's the reason you needed a different `path` to `python` executable.